# How to start background repeat-y after 46px space?

Tags: css, xhtml

```
#data-wrapper {
background:url("../images/repeat-bg.png") repeat-y 0 46px transparent;}
```

I want to start `repeat-bg.png` as a `repeat-y` but after `46px` area from top of `#data-wrapper`. Is it possible to do like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the background image to a containing div with 46px margin.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#container {
background:url("../images/repeat-bg.png") repeat-y; margin-top:46px; height:600px;}
/* height:600px is only critical to the demo code and can be removed once the page has content */
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<!--All of your content goes here-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition to this method, if support for this is not critical, you could be forward thinking and adopt the currently *very* under-supported CSS3 multiple-background declaration.

```
body {background:url("bg1.png") top no-repeat, url("bg2.png") bottom repeat-y;}
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean so that the top 46 Pixels have no background image?

No, that's not possible, sorry. You'll have to work around it, e.g. using another `div` with a margin.

Comment: Right. I want to start image after 46px area from top so background of top 46px should be transparent