# repeat-y left 50px repeats image on top as well

Tags: css

I have the following rule:

```
background: url(../img/redlines.png) repeat-y left 50px;
```

As you can see, the background image should start 50px below its div, and it works with `no-repeat`, but if I set `repeat-y` part of the image shows up at top of the div as well.

Any way to avoid this, and to keep repeating downwards only?

Comment: forgot to add image/link to jsfiddle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start background repeat-y after 46px space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970064/how-to-start-background-repeat-y-after-46px-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it's supposed to function. For a tiled image, the position is merely the starting position. I would suggest something like:

#### HTML

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.foo {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.bar
    background: url(../img/redlines.png) repeat-y left top;
}
.content {
    margin-top: -50px;    
}
```

Comment: I see. So it's normal behaviour. This is what I wanted to check.

Answer (score 1):

When you use repeat-y, adding 50px to the top only changes the floating point of where the repeat starts.

You will need to add margin or relative/absolute positioning to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

as you haven't provided a jsfiddle or any images, i'm assuming you could try `background-position` attribute in css.

refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Answer (score 0):

you may try **:after** on your container, see this example:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ln880p2/1/)

```
<div id="test"></div>
#test {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position:relative;
}

#test:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background: url(http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg) repeat-y left;
}
```